# Is it faster to do several matrix multiplication in paralel or sequentionaly?

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, compiler-optimization, intel-mkl

I need to multiply N matrix pairs. If we are multiplying  matrcies sequentionaly compler can use all cores for multiplucation of pair of matrix if they are large enough. Let say for simplicity that we do elementwise multiplication
 But paralization still will not be optimal.

From the other side we can multiply K matrix pair in paralel using single thread multiplication where K is the number of cores. I  think that in such way will have much more cach misses rate and this way will be slower. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Parallelization is usually faster than serialization, unless you have massive overhead for splitting your computation. So the question you're asking is "can we efficiently split this multiplication?"

Yes we can, and we can speed results practically on the order of Θ(n^2). [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm), especially the sections on cache behavior. Good luck!

Comment: What is "serialization" in this case?

Comment: Doing the computation one step at a time, rather than splitting and processing concurrently: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization